# spring 406 error when trying to get a single parameter from url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting "The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers." (http status 406 )error while  trying to get item_id parameter from url like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/products/edit_item.html?item_id=3
```

Then I will get item_id and get that single item data from database. I am using Spring 3.2.4 Tomcat 7 and eclipse kepler. My controller method is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="edit_item",method=RequestMethod.GET, params="item_id")
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView editItem(@RequestParam(value="item_id") int item_id)
{
    //do things with item_id
}
```

I have searched web and saw problems about json. My problem is very simple I just need to get single value from url. I am new to spring maybe this can be so easy issue for you, but I couldn't make it.

And the configuration file spring-servlet.xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd


    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context


    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
 <import resource="./Ekle/Beans.xml" />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="Ekle" />


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/Ekle/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And this is my stacktrace:

```
 Sep 22, 2013 10:31:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\Driver;;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.1.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.1.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin;.
Sep 22, 2013 10:31:59 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DomainYonetim' did not find a matching property.
Sep 22, 2013 10:31:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 22, 2013 10:31:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 22, 2013 10:31:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 747 ms
Sep 22, 2013 10:31:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 22, 2013 10:31:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization started
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Sun Sep 22 10:32:02 PDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/Ekle/Beans.xml]
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:02 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/DomainEkle] onto handler 'domainEkleController'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/DomainEkle.*] onto handler 'domainEkleController'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/DomainEkle/] onto handler 'domainEkleController'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/domain_list] onto handler 'domainEkleController'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/domain_list.*] onto handler 'domainEkleController'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/domain_list/] onto handler 'domainEkleController'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/memur_ekle] onto handler 'memurController'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/memur_ekle.*] onto handler 'memurController'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/memur_ekle/] onto handler 'memurController'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/memur_list] onto handler 'memurController'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/memur_list.*] onto handler 'memurController'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/memur_list/] onto handler 'memurController'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/sunucu_ekle] onto handler 'sunucuKontroller'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/sunucu_ekle.*] onto handler 'sunucuKontroller'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/sunucu_ekle/] onto handler 'sunucuKontroller'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/sunucu_list] onto handler 'sunucuKontroller'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/sunucu_list.*] onto handler 'sunucuKontroller'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/sunucu_list/] onto handler 'sunucuKontroller'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/sunucu_duzenle] onto handler 'sunucuKontroller'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/sunucu_duzenle.*] onto handler 'sunucuKontroller'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/sunucu_duzenle/] onto handler 'sunucuKontroller'
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 1088 ms
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 22, 2013 10:32:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
```

Comment: Please include the request headers

Comment: I have only configuration about request headers in spring-servlet.xml file. I included it.

Comment: I mean the actual HTTP request headers you're sending to your application.

Comment: I am sorry , I don't have any headers in the referrer page. I just make a link to application jsp page like this http://localhost:8080/products/edit_item.html?item_id=3 Probably I have some very beginner level mistakes of understanding Java Spring Framework basics.

Comment: Could you paste the complete stacktrace into your question

Comment: have you tried to use curl with the same url?